# Что значит ‹‹ибо››

Tags: перевод

Я видел, что ‹‹ибо›› значит ‹‹потому что›› или ‹‹так как››. Как можно употреблять это слово?

Comment: As a separate word it almost gone (apart from some phrases mentioned by Eugene) but actually либо - slightly obsolete compared to `или` but still quite widely used - consists of "ли" + "ибо".

Comment: ибо means because

Comment: Употреблять "ибо" следует торжественно, с указательным пальцем в потолок.

Comment: Anixx, ибо means "for"

Answer (score 10):

It's a Church Slavonic loanword, meaning "because", "due to".

You use it whenever you want to give your speech grand style, in the same way you would use "for" in the sense of "because" in English:

> Блаженны нищие духом, ибо их есть Царство Небесное // Blessed are the poor in spirit, for theirs is the kingdom of Heaven

Comment: *Ибо* is by far not as archaic as that. You'd have to use *поелику* to get the effect you describe. I'd say *ибо* ranks somewhere with "for" being used in the causative sense.

Comment: @NikolayErshov: http://i.imgur.com/f7FdEdG.jpg

Comment: @NikolayErshov ещё `понеже`

Answer (score 10):

Слово "ибо" относится почти исключительно к книжной речи и в разговорном стиле, если и употребляют, то, как правило, в ироничном ключе.

В книжной речи, особенно религиозного характера, предлог ибо по прежнему встречается и воспринимается вполне органично.

> "Прости им, **ибо** не ведают что творят" - [Лука 23;34]
>
> И брата он убил ради ее спасенья, **ибо** ему казалось нетерпимым, чтобы
>   нежнейшая, без злобы, женщина страдала от тяжелейшей надменности
>   супруга. [Т. Тархов. Меж двух времен. Хроники Уильяма Шекспира //
>   «Наука и жизнь», 2006]

Другие примеры употребления предлога "ибо" можно посмотреть на сайте ["Нацкорпус"](http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E8%E1%EE)

В целом, в непосредственном общении, не являясь носителем языка, слово лучше не употреблять, так как он вряд ли будет уместным. При написании научного или публицистического текста предлог употреблять можно, но в меру. Если текст религиозного характера, то можно смело заменять на "ибо" все "так как" и "потому что", следя только за отсутствием тавтологии.

Comment: "так как она вряд ли будет уместным" - оно?

Comment: @AlexB. спасибо, исправил.

Answer (score 8):

Из толкового словаря Даля (1866):

Ибо - причинный союз, малоупотребительный.
Синонимы - потому что, а потому и, так.
Вместо: не дам, ибо ты не заслужил, говорят: не дам, потому что ты не заслужил; не заслужил, а потому и не дам; не заслужил, так и не дам. Нередко частица эта только подразумевается: Не ходи, [ибо] убьют.

Из толкового словаря под редакцией Д.Н. Ушакова (2009):

Ибо, союз (книжное, устарелое). Потому что, так как (но создает меньшую, чем эти союзы зависимость причинного предложения от главного, скорее присоединяет логическое обоснование, причину, чем подчиняет одно предложение другому; поэтому перед ним часто возможна постановка точки вместо запятой). «Переезжая быстрые речки, не должно смотреть на воду, ибо тотчас голова закружится.» Лермонтов.

По моему опыту в современной речи это слово почти не используется, вместо него используют ‹‹потому что›› или ‹‹так как››

Answer (score 2):

По своему прямому значению "ибо" сейчас практически не используется, но применятся для придания тексту/речи ироничного стиля «под старину».

Также есть устойчивое выражение "[ибо нехуй](https://lurkmore.co/%D0%98%D0%B1%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B9)" и интернет-мем "[ибо ваистену](https://lurkmore.co/%D0%98%D0%B1%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83)".

Эти примеры являются грубыми и/или малопонятными, употреблять их в разговоре с малознакомыми людьми не сто́ит.

Comment: и чуть более цензурное "ибо нефиг"

Answer (score 2):

Слово **ибо** сейчас нигде не употребляется, его использование имеет только слэнговый характер в разговорной речи. В единственно возможном применении **ибо нефиг** эта фраза может произнесена после того, как некто совершил какое-то дерзкое действие, которое было запрещено и за это поплатился (травма, штраф, утрата). Например: "Сосед ремонтировал машину и сломал двигатель", "Неудивительно, **ибо нефиг** лезть туда, в чём не разбираешься". В этом диалоге использование **ибо нефиг** обосновано тем, что фраза легче произносится и имеет саркастический оттенок. Если заменить **ибо нефиг** на фразу **потому что не стоило** в диалоге, то вторая реплика будет звучать чересчур книжно, к тому же она будет иметь такой же смысл, если из неё удалить слово **ибо**, именно поэтому применение слова **ибо** - исключительно саркастическое, как связующее слово оно не используется нигде и никогда ни в разговоре, ни в литературе. В некоторых старых текстах и в редких книгах это слово обозначает **потому что**.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the most direct English counterpart is "thus".

It is also used in written language only and mostly for pretence or fake pathos.